# Unable to extract href data from html

Tags: ms-access, vba, href

I am using vba for url navigation,I am unable extract href value using below mentioned code,if possible please modify code for proper href value i.e link value

```
IE.navigate "http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B00IKFN8YM/ref=olp_page_2?ie=UTF8&f_new=true"
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or _
          IE.Busy = True
          On Error Resume Next
         ' MsgBox (ie.ReadyState)
     DoEvents
  Loop

 'Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set html = IE.Document
Set priceData2 = html.getElementsByClassName("a-column a-span3  olpDeliveryColumn").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each Item In priceData2
Debug.Print Item.innerHTML
Priceval2 = Item.innerHTML
MsgBox (Priceval2)
Next Item
```

From above mentioned url i want to extract following href value.

```
a href="/gp/aag/details/ref=olp_merch_ship_1?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=B00IKFN8YM&amp;seller=A294EA9HAL0DUF&amp;sshmPath=shipping-rates#aag_shipping"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to look for the tag "a" most likely.

```
Set sellerurl = html.getElementsBytagName("a")
```

This will then give you a HTMLAnchorElement which you can then get the href from.

**Answer updated: Try this**

```
Set sellerurl = html.getElementsBytagName(“a”)

For Each Item In sellerData
    debug.Print(Item.innerhtml)
    selleu = Item.href
Next Item
```

You should also see the links you are expecting in what is printed out.

Comment: thanks for your response,actully there is no tag a with href,sample html code is given below

Comment: <span class="a-list-item"><a class="a-link-normal" title="FriJa TT-Shop &amp;amp; Mehr" href="/s/ref=sr_in_-2_p_6_17?fst

Comment: Well Tahis, the `<a ...` definitely is an `a` tag!

Comment: thanks.Now i use below mentioned code but still href value is blank     Set sellerurl = html.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
For Each Item In sellerurl
surl2 = Item.href
'surl2 = surl.href
Exit For
Next Item

Comment: Is there any change required in above code for href value?..thanks

Comment: HTML is given below    <a class="a-link-normal" title="Adventure Northumberland" href="/s/ref=sr_in_-2_p_6_0?fst=as%3Aoff&amp;rh=n%3A318949011%2Cp_6%3AA3P5ROKL5A1OLE%7CA1HZ5FPD8FVC3N&amp;bbn=318949011&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1455355708&amp;rnid=401720011"><span class="refinementLink">Adventure Northumberland</span>

Comment: Now <a tag complete html exist above,Please check..thanks

Comment: try what I have put above. What is printed out in the result? Does it error?

Comment: No there is no error but value is blank as there is no href value..thanks

Comment: Following code display only one link url and page have more than 20 links.Set sellerurl = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each Item In sellerurl
  Debug.Print (Item.innerHTML)
    surl = Item.href
'Exit For
Next Item

Comment: Then this object "html" is the wrong one to use.  My first guess is that your website has frames.

Comment: Please check below mentioned page,i require links from this page.http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/search/other/ref=sr_sa_p_6?rh=n%3A318949011%2Cp_6%3AA3P5ROKL5A1OLE&bbn=318949011&pickerToList=enc-merchantbin&ie=UTF8&qid=1455259682

Comment: r u able to navigate above url?